# error: package com.facebook.android does not exist in android studio project

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I am new to android studio.I am developing an app which uses Facebook SDK.I have downloaded Facebbok SDK and imported it as a module to my android project.I am using latest version of android studio.So I simply imported it and did not make any change in other files for this.First I am trying to use facebook login functionality.But when I build the app I am getting following error.

```
     error: package com.facebook.android does not exist
```

I could see one solution as an answer to someone's question. But i could not understand it.Please somebody help me.

Comment: Hi show please gradel files of yore project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

check you build.gradle
it should got this dependency

if you got library project:

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':facebook');

}
```

if you got jar files in libs folder:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

}
```

or just add maven central dependency to:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.asne.facebook:facebook:3.17.2'
}
```

Comment: Is 3.17.2 the version? I see another answer below with the following line: compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0' What would be the difference? What are the potential risks of using one version or another?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add dependencies on your gradle file :-

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

above is path you need to add `dependencies {}` like below :-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the facebook library is jar file or library project?
If is jar file, you just need to add jar file in libs folder and dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
} in build.gradle.
If is library project, you should modify your setting.gradle and build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line of code to the dependencies in the build.gradle file helped me get rid of the same error.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

From [platform=android facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/387026448146821/)
-the last line of the section "Add Facebook SDK to Your Project")